# Как убрать автозаполнение текста коммита в IntellijIdea

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто пользуется IntellijIdea, как убрать авто комментарий с коммита? Тоесть когда я делаю коммит, то поле с комментарием должно быть пустое. 
Идея делает пакость подставляя текст предыдущего коммита.... 
В интернете не нашел ответ на даный вопрос(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как убрать авто комментарий с коммита?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]